# Google Federated Login vs Hybrid Protocol vs Google Data Authentication. Whats's the Difference?

Tags: python, openid, oauth, google-data

I am trying to implement Google Authentication in my website, in which I would also be pulling some Google Data using the Google Data API and I am using Google App Engine with Jinja2.

My question is, so many ways are mentioned to do it. I am confused between Google Federated Login,Google Data Protocol, Hybrid Protocol. Are these things the same or different ways to do the same thing.

From what I read and understood, which might be incorrect, Google Federated Login uses the hybrid protocol to authenticate and fetch the google data.

Is there a proper guide to implement any one of these in python. Examples which I found at the google link are kind of different. From what I understood,correct me if i am wrong, I have to implement only the OpenID Consumer part.

In order to implement Google Federated Login in Python, I saw that we need to download a separate library from the openid-enabled.com but I found a different library for the google data implementation at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

As you can see, I am confused a lot :D. Please help me  :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article specifically on [Retrieving Authenticated Google Data Feeds with Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/gdata.html)

The way I understand this example:

- You use the [gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to set up this AuthSub interaction
  [image: AuthSub]
- `gdata.auth.extract_auth_sub_token_from_url` extracts the token you get from AuthSub (step 4 above)
- you can now use this token to access Google Data.